# PosgreSQL: цикл по полям

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sqlite

Дана таблица с контрактами, необходимо для каждого contract.id просуммировать задолженность в таблице invoiceT. (Задолженность - когда invoice.payed = "false")
Записать результат в таблицу resT в виде: contract_id, amount

Вот мой псевдокод:

```
foreach contract in bill.contract contractT
loop
  foreach invoice in (select* from bill.invoice invoiceT
                  where invoiceT.id_contract = contract.id)
  sum = 0;
  loop
    if inv.payed = 'false' then
      sum := sum + inv.amount;
    end if;
  end loop;
  insert into debtorsT (id_contract, amount) values (contr.id, sum);
end loop;
```

Приму любой вариант реализации. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно я не понял вашу задачу - но для чего вам вовсе циклы? Задача решается элементарным стандартным SQL

```
select id_contract, sum(amount)
from bill.invoice
where payed = 'false' -- если там text или enum, если bool - то напрямую not payed
group by id_contract
```

Всё, получили выборку со суммой всех неоплаченных инвойсов. Если надо куда-то записать в другую таблицу - есть замечательный синтаксис `insert .. select ..`:

```
insert into debtorsT (id_contract, amount)
select id_contract, sum(amount)
from bill.invoice
where payed = 'false' -- если там text или enum, если bool - то напрямую not payed
group by id_contract
```

Если нужны ещё и полностью оплаченные контракты то просто добавляется left join:

```
select id_contract, coalesce(notpayed, 0)
from bill.contract
left join (
select id_contract, sum(amount) as notpayed
from bill.invoice
where payed = 'false' -- если там text или enum, если bool - то напрямую not payed
group by id_contract
) np on id_contract = contract.id
```

Это стандартные возможности SQL и потому подойдут и для postgresql и для упомянутых на момент написания ответа в тегах sqlite и mysql.

Comment: Спасибо большое) Я подозревал, что на самом деле всё проще :)